# Slice a list of dictionaries to preserve a range of items

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this, but much bigger:

```
newlist = sorted(l, key=lambda k: k['score'], reverse=True) 
[{'score': '4.0', 'id': 686}, {'score': '3.0', 'id': 55}, {'score': '2.0', 'id': 863}, {'score': '1.0', 'id': 756}]
```

However, what I am looking for is a way to sort the elements, but preserve only the first 10 dictionaries and discard the other ones. **The list of dicts must have only 10 dicts sorted by the higher score.**

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: `newlist = sorted(l, key=lambda k: k['score'], reverse=True)[:10]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fairly small list, you can sort them and take top 10 by slicing

Time: O(nlog n)  : n is the number of items in the original list

```
l = [{'score': '4.0', 'id': 686}, {'score': '3.0', 'id': 55}, {'score': '2.0', 'id': 863}, {'score': '1.0', 'id': 756}]
newlist = sorted(l, key=lambda k: k['score'], reverse=True)[:10]
newlist
```

if you have a large list you can get the max every time and append it to your list. This will be efficient than sorting if number of elements is high

Time: O(kn)  : n is the number of items in the original list and you want top k items

```
l = [{'score': '4.0', 'id': 686}, {'score': '3.0', 'id': 55}, {'score': '2.0', 'id': 863}, {'score': '1.0', 'id': 756}]
result = []
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    if len(l)<=0:break
    m = max(l, key=lambda k: k['score'])
    l.remove(m)
    result.append(m)
result
```

Output is same:

```
[{'id': 686, 'score': '4.0'},
 {'id': 55, 'score': '3.0'},
 {'id': 863, 'score': '2.0'},
 {'id': 756, 'score': '1.0'}]
```

**SUMMARY**:

if `k<log(n)` do max approach otherwise sort

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a subscription and the `sorted()` method with a custom key:

```
l = l[:10] # Overwrite l so it contains only the first 10 dicts

def s(dct):
    return dct['score'] # Returns the score of the dict

sorted(l,key=s) # Sort l with the key

print(l)
```